# Running c++ program with Cron

Tags: c++, cron

I'm trying to run a c++ program on my server, which, for now, is updating a MySQL database. I'm running it with Cron. The program is compiling and running on my own computer (Ubuntu 10.10), but I can seem to get something working on my server.

I checked if cron is working for me with a PHP script, but I don't know what to do to run a c++ program. In directAdmin I'm using the command:

```
/home/rogier/domains/ditiseenwinkel.nl/public_html/test/program &>/home/rogier/domains/ditiseenwinkel.nl/public_html/test/testsql2.log
```

Where `program` is my compiled program. Strange thing: the logfile is empty.

What am I doing wrong? And how should I run a c++ program via Cron?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does the program run without cron on the server?

Comment: Does your program rely on env variables ?

Comment: Have you made the file executable?

Comment: @PW. with env vars you mean includes/libraries? Yes it does...

Comment: @acraig5075: yes I did, but I made it on my computer. Not on my server.. I actually don't know how to do that...

Comment: by env variables I mean "environment variables".

Comment: @Rogier: You need to somehow get command line access to the server, say for instance using ssh. Then `sudo chmod u+x filename` will make it executable.

Comment: by the way: should there be a dot in front of the cron line? When I do that, the log file tells me '/bin/sh: ./home/rogier/domains/ditiseenwinkel.nl/public_html/test/program: No such file or directory'

Comment: @acraig5075: oh that's what you mean, sorry! Yes I did that: I changed it via FTP to 744.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was the program compiled on the same server? If not - you should compile the sourcecode on the same server.

Comment: No, it was not compiled on my server. How can I do that? It's not my server as in my hardware ;)

Comment: You should ALWAYS compile your programs on the same server. To compile it use 'g++ -o fileName fileName.cpp' or 'gcc -o fileName fileName.cpp'. -o tells the compiler the name of the executable, that you want.

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm in the stage again where cron was needed. Off course you all were right: I now have my own server, installed everything like I needed to have it, compiled the program and well... it's working! Thanks for convincing me :)

Answer (score 0):

A C++ program should be compiled into an executable. Once you get that far the language it was written in doesn't matter any more!

Does the command line given run on the server and produce output (i.e. via command line, not cron)? If so the app may be depending on some environment that cron doesn't have.

What about running it without redirection?

Do you have write permission to the logfile?

Comment: I was trying to run it via cron, because I don't have command line access. I'll try to get that!

Answer (score 0):

To Cron, it does not matter which type of program C++/PHP/Python/..etc you are running as far as you can execute that command from the shell. If a command you write on the shell works, it should work for cron too.

However be aware that the environment vars for cron might be completely different. That is the number 1 cause of problems with cron. Even if you install a cron script for your own user, you might be surprised that the cron environment does not have any PATH. Hence you have to specify  the full path for simple system commands lie /bin or /usr/bin

Like other users said, there might be a case of access rights if the command is executed by other user than yours. I usually test my dump files with the safest path "/tmp" (except if the user is chrooted)

Comment: What do you mean by env vars? Libraries / includes?

Comment: any environment variable. Those variable you see when you type "env" or "set" in your command prompt

Comment: That's a long list :) As you've noticed, I'm new to this (shell programming?). So what should I do now? Thank you so much!